# Mobile Safari - link to MP3 and show album art?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, streaming, mp3

I've created a web page that has a link to an MP3 file. When I click the link, the OS plays the MP3 with a full screen image of a generic image:

[image]

Is it possible to show album art in this view? I've embedded album art in the MP3 file, but it doesn't show up so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the sound creation tool or if there is something special that needs to be done with how the file is hosted.

Has anyone seen a song that plays from a web page with album artwork?

Comment: I wonder what ever happened to Podcast Producer? This is clearly possible since iTunes Radio will do this, and spottily an other apps do this - but it's an interesting question of whether the artwork comes "in-band" as part of the data stream of the file and mobile safari discards that data or if the web server isn't serving that data up from the link.

Comment: How are you hosting with ?

Comment: I am hosting both the MP3 and the simple, single page html site with Amazon S3.

Comment: Please state what MP3 player are you using, since the problem might be there.

Comment: @Buscar I'm using the iOS default. Whatever it is that launches when you click on a link to an MP3 in safari. Not sure if it's part of Safari, or the OS Quicktime Player...

Comment: Most websites have embedded simple (or complex) mp3 player, so the question is to find out which one are you using on the hosting site.

Comment: @Buscar If you re-read the question, I'm not using an embedded mp3 player on any hosted site. I'm talking about how iOS and Safari/Quicktime handles a request to an MP3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it cannot be done. The generic image which mentioned is just an indication that the music is being played by QuickTime plugin and you cannot change it to the music's artwork.

If you really want to see the artwork while playing the music, you need to use an application on your server side so that the application plays it, such as available media players which usually use Flash to provide such features.

Hope it helps you.

Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, but have you tried using an AAC-file with either that or Apple's M4A-extension? You could also try use the MP4-extension and see if it thinks the artwork is a frame from a video-file.

Comment: Using iMovie with the mp3 as the audio stream and the album art as the video stream and exporting to .mov should work as well.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done quite easily! You just have to embed the album art into the .mp3, which can be done with itunes and a special script.

Follow this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oClIT8f6V7E

Script download: http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=embedart

Comment: I've tried embedding artwork into the .mp3 files, it doesn't make a difference. Is there something special about the way iTunes does it? Do you have a link to an .mp3 where this is working?

Comment: Just tried embedding artwork with iTunes. Makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite an easy thing to do. Basically what you are trying to do is re/sign the 'tag' of a music file. The 'tag' defines the music file's appearance.

This can be done in [iTunes directly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seqL90t3iP8), for Windows/Linux there is [EasyTag](https://projects.gnome.org/easytag/) ([Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDMp7y0RfEY)).

Comment: Answers on Ask Different should be more than just a link (or a collection of links). It's ok to reference material from other sites but please include the key elements directly in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand on its own.

Comment: In addition how does this differ from the answer given on August 1st which (based on the comments) seems not to solve the issue?

Comment: Because, from past experience, iTunes does not always resign the tag straight to the mp3 file but usually just how it is displayed on the iTunes program or in the iPhone music app. Where as Easy Tag can resign the actual file, not just how it is displayed.

Comment: @Condrum If I understand correctly, your suggesting to ensure the artwork is embedded in the mp3 file. I've checked, and it's definitely part of the mp3 file. It shows up when I put the file on my android phone (manual file transfer, no sync) but it never shows up in the safari browser.